# Image field on ReportViewer

Tags: reportviewer

Anybody tried to display image field (image/byte array) data type on reportviewer.

Regards, 
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  ReportViewer requires a Base64 Image encoding in order to display the image properly.

If your image is in a Byte array, it will need to be converted to Base64:

```
 Public Function ConvertImageToBase64String(ByVal img As Image) As String
    Dim output As String = ""

    Dim outputArray() As Byte
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream
    img.Save(stream, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    outputArray = stream.ToArray()
    stream.Close()
    output = Convert.ToBase64String(outputArray)

    Return output
  End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have with an image data type in SQL Server. Works fine with SSRS 2005 and 2008.